# biblatex don't show section

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

in my configuration for biblatex I added another sction for Images.

Here's my code so far:

```
\newcommand{\@bibtitle}{Quellenverzeichnis}
\newcommand{\@bibtitleLiteratur}{Literatur}
\newcommand{\@bibtitleAvmedia}{Filme und audiovisuelle Medien}
\newcommand{\@bibtitleOnline}{Online-Quellen}   
\newcommand{\@bibtitleImage}{Visuelle und graphische Medien}
\defbibfilter{literature}{
    not ( type=movie or type=video or type=image or type=music or type=audio or type=online or type=electronic or type=www or type=software )}   
\defbibfilter{avmedia}{
    ( type=movie or type=video or type=music or type=audio or type=software )}   
\defbibfilter{online}{
    ( type=online or type=electronic or type=www )}    
\defbibfilter{image}{
    ( type=image)}
%some other code
\newcommand{\MakeBibliography}[1][]{
    \clearpage
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{nosplit}}
        {
            \printbibheading[heading=bibintoc,title={\@bibtitle}]
            \begin{bibhyphenation}  
            \printbibliography[heading=noheader]
            \end{bibhyphenation}
        }
        {
            \printbibheading[heading=bibintoc,title={\@bibtitle}]
            \begin{bibhyphenation}
            \printbibliography[filter=literature,heading=subbibintoc,title={\@bibtitleLiteratur}]
            \printbibliography[filter=avmedia,heading=subbibintoc,title={\@bibtitleAvmedia}]
            \printbibliography[filter=image,heading=subbibintoc,title={\@bibtitleImage}]
            \printbibliography[filter=online,heading=subbibintoc,title={\@bibtitleOnline}]
            \end{bibhyphenation}
        }
}
```

However, if I declare

```
@image{pr_tabelle,
    url={http://de.onpage.org/wiki/images/2/29/PageRank2.jpg}
}
```

It's not shown in the Bibliography, whereas

```
@online{explorer,
author={{Siddharth}},
title={9 Most Common IE Bugs and How to Fix Them},
year={2009},
url={http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/9-most-common-ie-bugs-and-how-to-fix-them--net-7764}
}
```

doesn't seem to be a problem.

Comment: Could you post a complet [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)?

Comment: also, I don't think there is a driver for `@image`. You either need to create one, or use an existing one.

Comment: @RunarTrollet so I could basically use www or misc ?

Comment: Impossible to know without an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). but you could try with `@online` and then try some others.

Comment: Interestingly `type=image` instead of `filter=image` works just fine.

Comment: @moewe solved the problem, thank you very much :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because solved in comments